Bash Script Checking Git Main Branch is Erroring
I've written a script to update my git repos automatically.
It worked until I added a check as to whether the current branch was the main branch.
At this point, the script bombs out on the line of the if guards saying:

[[main: command not found

The script is:
#!/bin/bash

api='/C/Repos/me/services/api'

declare -a reposArray=($api)

for repo in "${reposArray[@]}"
do
    echo
    echo "updating $repo"
    cd $repo
    echo "fetching code"
    #git fetch --prune
    
    branch="$(git branch --show-current)"
    
    if [["$branch" != "main"]]; then
        git switch main
    fi  
    
    echo "merging remote into main"
    git merge
done

Any idea what is wrong?
Does main have a special meaning such that it needs to be escaped?
How would I escape a whole word like that?
Cheers

Unless switch is an alias for checkout it's going to continue to fail. Also could check for 'master' in case of legacy repos, but if you've updated your repos to all use main instead obviously that won't matter.

switch is a git command. Not an alias. It is preferred to checkout these days. checkout got too overloaded.

The issue in your script is due to the syntax error in the if statement. The correct syntax for comparing strings in Bash requires spaces between the brackets and the condition. Additionally, you should use quotes around variables to prevent issues with spaces or special characters.

#!/bin/bash
    
    api='/C/Repos/me/services/api'
    
    declare -a reposArray=($api)
    
    for repo in "${reposArray[@]}"
    do
        echo
        echo "updating $repo"
        cd "$repo"
        echo "fetching code"
        #git fetch --prune
        
        branch="$(git branch --show-current)"
        
        if [ "$branch" != "main" ]; then
            git switch main
        fi  
        
        echo "merging remote into main"
        git merge
    done

I've added spaces around [ and ] in the if statement, as well as quotes around the variable $branch. This should resolve the "command not found" error you were encountering.

good eye and thank you. I had a gut feeling it was some kind of spacing thing, as I had already fixed that in another part of the script. I'm still not massively knowledgeable about bash script syntax. Cheers.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

No I don't use GPT.

Most your answers appears to be ChatGPT-created. Please read the attached article. TLDR: Using ChatGPT to create any content is banned - screen | screen and not lets forget this question where you "created" two almost identical answers
